# Azure Batch API rising 'AttributeError' in ML notebook

Tags: python, azure, azure-batch, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to interact with Azure Batch with python API, in the following way:

```py
from azure.batch import BatchServiceClient
batch = BatchServiceClient('<mycredential>','https://<mybatchaccount>.<region>.batch.azure.com')
next(batch.job.list())
```

This is run in a ML Studio notebook.

However the following error appears: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'signed_session'`.
I am taking the url and credentials from my batch console UI:

[image]

As a credential I tried both Primary and Secondary access keys amd "URL" as batch url.
Am I doing anything wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<mycredential>` should not be your bare auth key string. You need to create a shared auth key object.

```
credentials = batchauth.SharedKeyCredentials(BATCH_ACCOUNT_NAME, BATCH_ACCOUNT_KEY)
batch_client = batch.BatchServiceClient(credentials, base_url=BATCH_ACCOUNT_URL)
```

Please see the [Azure Batch Python tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/tutorial-parallel-python).